# Why my sql select statement return empty value when selecting multiple row in database?

Tags: php, mysql

When I select in my database multiple row, the answer is always empty (but have the good number of response).

Example : I search in my database all the t_user.id of user name "Bob", and I have 4 Bob in my database :
- The while goes loop 4 times (four occurence of "id :"),
- But all the answer will be empty ($data['id'] display no data).

When I select only one row, the select return value (if I search the t_user.name by t_user.id, I have a data).

It's been two days now that I'm struggling to find a solution, if anyone had one ?

```php
$i = 0;
$beginning_name = 'Bob';

//ServerConnection::connectionDAO() return the PDO connection
$req = ServerConnection::connectionDAO()->prepare('SELECT t_user.id FROM t_user WHERE name = :name');

$req->execute(array(
    'name' => $beginning_name
));

while($data = $req->fetch()){
    echo "id :".$data['id'];
    $i++;
}
```

I haven't any error message.

I'm using PHP 7

Comment: `ServerConnection::connectionDAO()` gives back a successful PDO connection? Anything in error log, exceptions enabled? Do you get back `id :` 4 times or nothing?

Comment: Yes, ```ServerConnection::connectionDAO()``` gives back a successful PDO connection, and yes I get back ```4 id :```

Comment: `var_dump($data);`

Comment: Try `t_user.id as id FROM` likely the issue is that the PHP index includes the table name. An alias in the query should resolve that.

Comment: ```var_dump($data)``` give me =>```bool(true)```,
```t_user.id as id```  : same result

Comment: PHP is using a Java jar file for doing PDO? Sounds questionable. Also, isn't the parameter being passed to execute missing a colon as in `':name' => $beginning_name`?

Comment: "PHP is using a Java jar file for doing PDO", yep totally stupid, i will update the question without that. ```':name' => $beginning_name``` i'm not using the ```:``` in my other sql statement and they work, but I'm testing (and same result).

Comment: `var_dump($data)` will give you `bool(false)` if the fetch fails or it will return you an array representing the next row. I don't see how it returned `bool(true)`.

Comment: Your call to `connectionDAO` returns a connection but that reference is not being maintained after it is used to call `prepare`. Perhaps it is being garbage collected (not likely because the statement probably refers to the connection). Try `$conn =  ServerConnection::connectionDAO();` followed by `$req = $conn->prepare...`.  Before doing the prepare call, insert: `$conn.setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` to make sure an exception is thrown on an error.

Comment: Just try, same : ```var_dump($data)``` give ```bool(true)```.

Comment: I did try and it doesn't.

Comment: I retry, and it's working. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't "SELECT t_user.id FROM ..." be: "SELECT * FROM ..." ?

Comment: No, why would it be? It is never recommended to `SELECT *` especially if you only want one column.